# Add two values together in Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

My Javascript / Mootools knowledge is limited, so I am having trouble figuring out how to take the following code and make it produce a sum and assign the value to the ordertotal variable.

```
$('ordertotal').value = '$' + 100 * $('tickets').value + 10 * $('fiftytickets').value + '.00';
```

The tickets variable is either 1 or 2 depending on the user selection and the fiftytickets variable is either 0.5, 2.5 or 5.0 depending of the user selection. Both variables are supplied values using a HTML select menu and they function correctly when used individually.

For example:

```
$('ordertotal').value = '$' + 100 * $('tickets').value + '.00';
```

Works correctly and

```
$('ordertotal').value = '$' + 10 * $('fiftytickets').value + '.00';
```

Works correctly, but I can figure out how to add them together and assign them to the ordertotal variable.

Any assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to get sum of `string + int + int + string`

Your two examples worked, because there was only concatenation (`string + int(converted to string) + string`)

And when you add a nubmer to a "$" - your number get converted to a string. What you can do is to either put numbers sum in () or get the value separately:

```
sumValue = 100 * $('tickets').value + 10 * $('fiftytickets').value
$('ordertotal').value = '$' + sumValue + '.00';
```

Example:

```
> "1" + 1
  "11"
> "$" + 1 + ".00"
  "$1.00"
> "$" + 1 + 1 + ".00"
  "$11.00"
> "$" + (1 + 1) + ".00"
  "$2.00"
```

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for detailing what I needed to change to make this work. I have that part working now, but I also need to figure out how to modify the following code to enable the Javascript addEvent change function to work when either of the two HTML select menus are used.

`$('tickets').addEvent('change', function() {`

Currently the total will only change if the user changes the tickets select menu, but I need it to work if they use the tickets or the fifty tickets select menus.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Mike

Comment: `$('tickets').on('change', function() {` ?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have adjusted the code, but Chrome developer tools displays this error **Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLSelectElement> has no method 'on'**. Do changes need to be made to the HTML select menu itself to make this code work?

Comment: Right... "Tickets" is not a valid selector... "#tickets" for I'd, ".tickets" for class

Comment: I tried changing the code to use the IDs of the select menus, but a different error is displayed. **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEvent' of null** or **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of null**.

Comment: Please post the full code. Preferably in a separate question.

Comment: New questions has been posted here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045981/update-text-input-field-dynamically-using-two-select-menus-with-javascript)

Comment: @mishik it is explicitly mentioned in the tags **and** the question's first paragraph that OP is coding with ***Mootools***. Your jQuery suggestions, which are incredibly invalid in Mootools, are thus extremely confusing to Mike, causing these 2 unneeded errors.