# Update text input field dynamically using two select menus with Javascript

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically update a text input field when a user changes the option in one or two HTML select menus. I have included my code below showing how it currently works.

```
$('tickets').addEvent('change', function() {
    if($('tickets').value > 0)
    {
        var cells = $$('.ticket2');
        cells.each(function(cell) { cell.setAttribute('style','display:none;');});
        var cells = $$('.ticket3');
        cells.each(function(cell) { cell.setAttribute('style','display:none;');});
        var sumValue = '$' + (100 * $('tickets').value + 10 * $('fiftytickets').value) + '.00';
        $('ordertotal').value = sumValue;
        $('ticket1heading').setHTML('Ticket(s)');
    } else {
        var cells = $$('.ticket2');
        cells.each(function(cell) { cell.setAttribute('style','');});
        var cells = $$('.ticket3');
        cells.each(function(cell) { cell.setAttribute('style','');});
        $('ticket2heading').setAttribute('style','text-align:center; font-weight:bold;');
        $('ticket3heading').setAttribute('style','text-align:center; font-weight:bold;');
        $('ordertotal').value = '$' + 250 + '.00';
        $('ticket1heading').setHTML('Ticket 1');
    }
});
```

The tickets select menu correctly affects the ordertotal text input field, but the fiftytickets select menu does not. I need the two to work independently of each other, but when each is changed, to affect the value of the ordertotal text input field.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Mike

Comment: `$('fiftytickets')` seems that you have a `<fiftytickets>` element in your DOM... Otherwise, see jQuery selector, and use something like `$('#elementId')`. Don't hesitate to create a Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @JoDev in Mootools `$('elementId')` is the correct syntax.

Comment: @OP: I'm not sure what elements you have and what you are trying to achieve. If you create a fiddle demonstrating the issue I'll gladly have a look.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Sorry for my confusion! And Thank you to correct me...

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I have created a fiddle with some adjustments to the code that have made it work, but I am sure it could be rewritten or optimized because it looks messy and my Javascript skills are lacking. You can review my Javascript here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mikehermary/M3MwW/3/)

Comment: Well it's not entirely working yet. Why are you using such an outdated version of Moo though? Current branch is 1.4.5, you included 1.2.6, any reason for that?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes The code is from a component created for Joomla 1.5 and the version of Mootools used is 1.12. That is why I chose 1.2.6. I noticed an issue when changing the tickets select menu back to group when the fiftytickets has a value other than no. Is this the issue you experienced?

Comment: Yep that's the issue. You have some real problems though - in 1.2 (several years ago now) a lot of breaking changes were implemented. 1.12 and 1.2+ are certainly not all too compatible. It's much like trying to run Office 2013 under Windows 95. I'd definitely consider upgrading it before doing anything else. [Both your Joomla and Mootools are several years outdated](http://www.rockettheme.com/blog/coding/946-supporting-mootools-112-and-12).

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I know Joomla and Mootools are outdated, but neither can be upgraded at this time for various reasons. Can you offer any tips on how to fix the issue I mentioned in my last post? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

as said by JoDev, the select element's object is referenced with $('#tickets') and not just $('tickets').
also, I don't think that there is a value property in jquery for a select element.
you can get the value with the val() function.

Created a little fiddle for you here [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcuzzo/AAUS7/3/)

```
$('#tickets').change(function() {
   $('#output').val($(this).val() + " - " + $('#fiftytickets').val());
});
$('#fiftytickets').change(function() {
   $('#output').val($('#tickets').val() + " - " + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: -1, the question is tagged MOOTOOLS, not JQUERY. There are, really, other Javascript libraries than jQuery, and you can even write Javascript without jQuery you know. The `$('tickets')` syntax is absolutely correct in Mootools.